# Javascript: can't see server cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, cgi

I'm creating a cookie manually on a server by setting the HTTP headers as follows:

```
Status: 200 OK
Set-Cookie: downloadDone=3196
Content-type: application/octet-stream
Content-disposition: attachment; filename="foo"
```

I can confirm on the Chrome and FF debuggers that the incoming header also looks like this. However, I can't read this cookie from Javascript. `document.cookie` is empty, and the Chrome debugger also shows it as empty:

```
document: document
  cookie: ""
```

Both Chrome and FF *do* actually set the cookie. They even send it back to the server on the next request; the debuggers show this in the request headers:

```
Cookie:downloadDone=3196
```

I don't think either browser thinks that `HttpOnly` is set, but both debuggers seem to be flakey on cookies, so I may be wrong.
Any idea why I can't see this in `document.cookie`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed, but I'm not happy with it. Both Firefox and Chrome require a non-default `Path` for the cookie to be visible to Javascript. This doesn't work:

```
Status: 200 OK
Set-Cookie: downloadDone=3196; Max-Age=3600
Content-type: application/octet-stream
Content-disposition: attachment; filename="foo"
```

but this *does* work:

```
Status: 200 OK
Set-Cookie: downloadDone=3196; Path=/; Max-Age=3600
Content-type: application/octet-stream
Content-disposition: attachment; filename="foo"
```

Before sending `Path`, the FF cookie browser was showing a default path of `/cgi-bin/`, and `document.cookie` was empty. After adding the path, the cookie browser correctly shows a path of `/`, and `document.cookie` now magically shows the cookie. I can't find this in the RFCs anywhere. At least one of the RFCs explicitly states that `name=value` is sufficient.